# Find $n$ when the coefficients of the $16^{th}$ and $26^{th}$ terms of $(1+x)^n$ are equal.

Tags: binomial-theorem

> Find $n$ when the coefficients of the $16^{th}$ and $26^{th}$ terms of $(1+x)^n$ are equal.

$16^{th}$ term coefficient: $^nC_{15}= \space ^nC_{n-15}$

$26^{th}$ term coefficient: $^nC_{25}= \space ^nC_{n-25}$

$\Rightarrow 15 = n-25 \Rightarrow n=40$ $\space$ or $\space$ $n-15=25 \Rightarrow n=40$

This is the correct answer. My question is since $^nC_{15}= \space ^nC_{25}$, why can't $n-15=n-25$? In this case $-15 \neq -25$, but if the algebra works would it be allowed? After all the question says the coefficients are equal. Thanks.

Comment: No, $\hspace{0pt}^nC_a = \hspace{0pt}^nC_b$ does not imply $a = b$. In general, having $f(a) = f(b)$ does not imply $a = b$, unless $f$ is injective/one-to-one (and this property is the very definition of being injective/one-to-one).

Comment: A quicker way is to use the symmetry of Pascal's triangle. The binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$ has $n+1$ terms. Start with $T_1 = T_{n+1}$ (actually both equal $1$ here), and as you go stepwise from the left, you'll find the terms are mirrored when you go stepwise from the right. To get to $T_{16}$ from the left hand side, you've added $15$ to the index, so subtract the same quantity from the right hand side to reach $T_{n-14}$. You're given this is the $26$th term, so $n-14 = 26 \implies n = 40$. You can use this "quick" method here because both coefficients in the binomial are $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for the same reason that $15\neq 25$ even though $\binom{n}{15}=\binom{n}{25}$

The question tells you two terms that are in different positions, 16th and 26th. To find the correct answer of $40$, you use the symmetry property to change *one* of these, so that you have two representations of the same position: $15, n-25$ or $25, n-15$.

If you use the symmetry property to change both positions, you're back to talking about different positions, hence it doesn't work.